# Image parallax horizontally on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these images on a page having Class & ID img1, and I want them to move aside when I scroll down and vice versa. I would be much obliged if you help me.

I have been using this CSS to make it up and down in a smooth way.
Thanks.

```css
    .img1 {
    -webkit-animation: mover 2s infinite  alternate;
    animation: mover 2s infinite  alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mover {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-20px); }
}
@keyframes mover {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-20px); }
}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code too.

Comment: <img src="http://nft.nayaab.world/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/cloud-22.png" style=" height: 200px; width:350px; " class="img1"></img>

Comment: I've added the HTML code to your question. Note that you can do so too by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72641880/edit), just below your question. Also, it's best to use dummy images for code snippets, as local images won't be displayed in your example.